# Hebrew characters are printed in reverse order in iText 7

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, right-to-left

I'm using iText 7 for printing some text in List (in Hebrew) to PDF file, but while printing the Hebrew characters are printed in a reverse way.
The input given was "קניון אם הדרך" while the data printed in PDF is "ךרדה םא ןוינק"

I have set the font encoding and the base direction for the elements but still the characters are printed in the reverse order.

Code to print list into the table in PDF:

```
public void PrintListData(string filename)
{
    var writer = new PdfWriter(filename);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
    SetFont(doc);
    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(2)).UseAllAvailableWidth();
    table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
    //table.SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    var index = 1;
    foreach (var item in _data)
    {
        
        var para = new Paragraph(item);
        para.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        //para.SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        table.AddCell(index.ToString());
        table.AddCell(para);

        index++;
    }
    
    doc.Add(table);
    doc.Close();
    Process.Start(filename);
}
```

Set font function

```
void SetFont(Document doc)
{
    FontSet _defaultFontSet = new FontSet();
    
    var fontFolders = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
    _defaultFontSet.AddFont(System.IO.Path.Combine(fontFolders, "arial.ttf"), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
    _defaultFontSet.AddFont(System.IO.Path.Combine(fontFolders, "arialbd.ttf"), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
    doc.SetFontProvider(new FontProvider(_defaultFontSet));
    doc.SetProperty(Property.FONT, new String[] { "MyFontFamilyName" });
    //doc.SetProperty(Property.BASE_DIRECTION, BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

}
```

I'm not sure to where should we set the text direction to print RTL.

Comment: I can't close as a duplicate because the question has no answers, but there is a link to a youtube tutorial in the comments that should help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61959671/3094533

Comment: In particular: Do you have the iText 7 pdfCalligraph add-on included in your project?

Comment: Is it mandatory to add pdfCalligraph add-on, because I think in the iTextSharp 5 version this wasn't required

Comment: iText 5 had only limited support for Hebrew which couldn't be expanded because of how it was built. The languages that were fully supported in iText 5 are still supported in iText 7 Core, while others are available in pdfCalligraph. Here is an [overview](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph). So yes, Hebrew requires pdfCalligraph.